# Using slashes in the where clause while comparing values in active record codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following query

```
$query="DELETE FROM salesinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceNumber=".$this->put('invoiceNumber');
```

Here `$this->put('invoiceNumber');` always have values like "M\34\SD". Due to slashes in values it doesn't work as expected.

**I researched and found the mysql_escape_string can be used for this purpose but its deprecated now as per the manual. So whats my best bet here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method in the activerecord called `escape`, so you should :

```
$invoice = $this->db->escape($yourVar);
$query = "DELETE FROM salesinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceNumber=$invoice";
```

Which will protect against sql injection as it escapes the var.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Codeingiter Active Record instead? An example:

```
$this->db->where('invoiceNumber', $this->put('invoiceNumber'));
$this->db->delete('salesinvoiceitems');
```

Taken from Codeigniter documentation:

> Beyond simplicity, a major benefit to using the Active Record features
>   is that it allows you to create database independent applications,
>   since the query syntax is generated by each database adapter. It also
>   allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically
>   by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$query="DELETE FROM salesinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceNumber=".addslashes($this->put('invoiceNumber'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try strip slashes

```
$query="DELETE FROM salesinvoiceitems WHERE invoiceNumber='".($this->put('invoiceNumber')). "'";
```